# Deleting a large file does not free up space

Tags: disk-usage

I deleted a large file (6 GB) located in my home directory but the free space is not increased.

I have tried looking the file in trash folder by typing `cd ~/.local/share/Trash/files` but it's not listed there. I have tried running `sudo apt-get clean` but the problem isn't solved. I have also tried `sudo lsof +L1` to see if any other process are using it but it's not showing up there either.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What is the file named? Can you run `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: You can run `df -lh` to see a list of your partitions including the free space. Even if the file is hidden (starts with a dot .), you should see it in the Nautilus Trash (also called Rubbish Bin).

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ: file is named output.file located in home directory. "fdisk -l" just gives the start and end Blocks of each partition. I don't know what to do with this data.

Comment: @rosch: file was not hidden(name wasn't started with a dot)

Comment: You may be trying to free space on the wrong partition. `fdisk` will tell me what partition is the one in question/

Answer (score 20):

The file is still in use by one (or more) process(es). The space occupied by the file will only be released if no processes have the file open.

This is a common gotcha with log files that are filling up a filesystem, when the administrator forgets to restart the accompanying process.

You can check this with `lsof | grep DEL`

Comment: Thanks for your reply
I don't think that the file was being used by any other process at that time. It was a binary file created using "truncate -s 10M output.file" just to meet the minimum sharing required to use DC++ :).

Comment: So is your question wrong then? You did not delete the file yet and after deleting you saw the free space?

Comment: @rosch: I deleted the file and after that I saw the space. Why else would I be asking question otherwise ?

Comment: Well your question is saying the opposite.."deleting a file does not free up space". So I suggest to rephrase it, or even delete it. I am thinking about people reading the question later on.

Answer (score 4):

I have resolved this by the following steps

```
#lsof +L1
```

Which will show the list of files that holding memory with deleted quote.

Note the pid ( Process id ) of the file

Kill the process

```
#kill <pid>
```

The memory will be released by the process

Check it by command

```
#df -h
```

Comment: saved my day, suprised that no one upvoted this answer.

Comment: you can check here too in this link I have explained more in detail in my answer for same scenario @Bloodmoon
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332629/rm-not-freeing-diskspace/48945282#48945282